# Swift2.1 call can throw but is not marked with try Error

Tags: swift2

my code is working in swift 2.0 but when i update code on swift 2.1 its Return me error "call can throw but is not marked with try" 
Please Give me solution 
Here is my code I have put this line there i get error in line "/****Here is Error****/"

```
  func connectionGetChannelFeed()
    {
         if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        let url : String = "\(WebServicesUrl.GlobalConstants.SiteUrl)get_favs.php?user_id=\(delegate.appd_userid)&at=0&channels"
        let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


            do {

          /****Here is Error****/
                let jsonResult: NSArray! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray

                self.delegate.ary_channelList = jsonResult;


            } catch {
                // handle error
            }



        })


         }else

         {

            JLToast.makeText("\(WebServicesUrl.MessageConstant.NetworkErrorMEssage)"  ,duration: WebServicesUrl.durationTime.timeDuration).show()



        }


    }
```

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 2):

try to add 'try':

```
let jsonResult: NSArray! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```